# Excel triggered macro

Tags: excel, vba, events, triggers

I am struggling to carry out the following. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The marco only relates to one excel worksheet.

I have 50 rows of information, 11 columns wide (A - K) 
in each row of column A there sits an IF condition
If the IF condition flags the word 'OK' 
I would like a macro to trigger, and carry out the following
to copy the information in cells B to K, and paste special it back into those cells.

And then move onto the next row

The 50 rows of information will fill up over the course of a day.

Each ROW condition in column A is executed only ONCE, starting with ROW 1 and working it's way down to ROW 50

The trigger event 'OK' will come, it is just a matter of waiting for it to happen.

As I say any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Change event of the sheet, see if the target is in the A column.
If it is check to see if it equals 'OK', then execute the macro on that row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
Dim TestRange As Range
Set TestRange = Target.Dependents

If TestRange.HasFormula And Err.Number = 0 Then
    If Left$(TestRange.Address, 2) = "$A" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If TestRange.Value = "OK" Then
            Call GreatMacro(TestRange)
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, I copied the code in but had an error msg when run saying 'wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'

Also with GreatMacro how do I get it to carry out ther copy & paste with the approprate cells


Sub GreatMacro()
'
'
    Range("B2:G2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

Also how do you copy and paste the relevant cells, this macro is tied to just ROW 2

My knowledge is limited. Many thanks for replying so promptly

Comment: There are a few ways.  I'll modify the code I gave you to Call GreatMacro(Target), then your GreatMacro will have a parameter of a range (say RowAddress), then your select statment will be RowAddress.Columns("B:G").Select.

Comment: Thanks Lance, Will you post the modified code? 

In terms of the execution of it will be very resource hungry when processing? and secondly if 4 cells come up with 'OK' will just process one row at a time, or will it try to do everything at once and lock up. Thanks again for taking the time out to post.

Comment: Also forgot to add Lance, if the first row to start from is A6, does a starting point need to be added or will the code just look down column A until it comes across a CELL with 'OK' in

Comment: ah yes and.. just to re-iterate the 'OK' in column A is a result of an =IF condition within that CELL being met.

Comment: You'll have to test it on simultaneous IFs, I would think the code could handle it, but haven't had to face that situation myself.  The starting point doesn't matter, since the Target is always whatever cell got changed.  I've already edited my code (only had to change the parameter).  I've found that this kind of simple event/macro stuff works very quickly, shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Hi Lance, put the code in and still coming up with the error 1) the macro is called GreatMacro (), do I need to change it to GreatMacro (Target)? and 2) I have the macro positioned just below your code in the Module -is this what is causing the problem

Comment: The macro (you can name it whatever you want) needs to have a Range parameter like so:  Public Sub GreatMacro(RowAddress As Range)

Comment: ok will put that in -came across the following in my seach for a solution.
If C6 is a formula then change it to this

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo EndMacro
If Not Target.HasFormula Then
Set rng = Target.Dependents
If Not Intersect(Range("C6"), rng) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Value <> "" Then
Range("D6").Value = Target.Value
End If
End If
End If
EndMacro:
End Sub

Regards Ron de Bruin
http://www.rondebruin.nl/tips.htm
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3636981.php

Comment: Thought it might be of interest -seeing as CELL A is triggered by a condition

Comment: Hi Lance, got it to work, however only when I type in 'OK', I think the formula does cause a problem -how would I incorporate the above code into your code?

Comment: We'll have to use some of the concepts he uses, but I need to know what your cell formula is that becomes "OK".

Comment: In COLUMN EO the cells have the formula =IF(EN6>EM6,"OK","") and the rows that need copying and then paste special are EP:EY. Thanks so much for your effort and input, very much appreciated

Comment: OK, I've edited to code to work for that specific situation, though you'll need to do some testing.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks Lance, will do some testing and report back

Comment: Hi Lance, notice that the CALL is for GreatMacro(TestRange) whereas the other macro is called GreatMacro(Rowaddress As Range) -do I need to change anything?

Comment: No, TestRange is the Range your sending to the subroutine, Rowaddress is what you're calling it inside the subroutine.

Comment: Actually Lance would it be better rather than CALL ing upon a macro because it is so short, could we not add it into your code -the code in GreatMacro was just     

Rowaddress.Columns("B:G").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: The reason for the above post, is that I'm having trouble getting it to run

Comment: Yes, you could just do that.  Just change Rowaddress to TestRange.

Comment: Be aware when testing this code, that if it faults out in the middle of the subroutine, you have to reset Application.EnableEvents = True (in the immediate Window, or you could close and reopen Excel).

Comment: Hi Lance it looks good, many thanks for both your help and time -very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Lance, seems to keep stopping, is there a way of getting the macro to start at CELL A7 and then wait until it gets 'OK', once it does it copies and pastes special and then moves down 1 row and waits there, and to keep doing this until it reaches a cell with 999 in?

Comment: oh yes one other additional point it keeps stopping on the line Set TestRange = Target.Dependents, hence the reason for the request above I thought by forcing it to start at a point and then wait for an 'OK' before being directed to the next cell/row would cure this

Comment: When you say stop, do you mean with an error, or is it just doing nothing?

Comment: It appears that the problem might be when the Target doesn't have any dependents.  There isn't much documentation out there on how to test to see if Target has any dependents, though you could always drop out on an error, but I'll do some research to see if there's a better way.

Comment: OK, I set it up so that Target.Dependents would be tested using exceptions.  Go ahead and see if that solves your problem.  Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/macro-when-excel-cell-changes.php) shows how you can set a macro to run on cell change.
Basically, the method is to over-use the worksheet change function, and if the cell is the correct one, you let the function run.

Try to keep as much as possible inside the if-this-is-correct-cell check to make sure that too much code isn't executing every single time you make a worksheet change.